# Using xpath on a String in Java?

Tags: java, xml, xpath

I've made code that sends an XML request to a server and delivers XML back to me (with nodes and all) and I was wondering how to go about using XPath to strip down the XML to just the content.
I have it working right now where I the returned string is saved into a external document, and then the Xpath reads the external document. But I'd like to cut out this process down.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Many XML libraries allow for String manipulation of XML & XPATH.

There are examples with dom4j [here](http://dom4j.sourceforge.net/dom4j-1.6.1/guide.html).

From the link provided:

```
String text = "<person> <name>James</name><address><city>New York</city></address></person><person> <name>Billy</name> </person>";
Document document = DocumentHelper.parseText(text);

List list = document.selectNodes( "//person/name" );
Node node = document.selectSingleNode( "//person/address/city" );
```

Comment: Could you explain the `@name` ? It seems strange because I am used to `@` meaning attribute. But in the string, provided, `name` is not an attribute.

Comment: I just copied it from the 'Powerful Navigation with XPath' example, there isn't really any text that matches it. You're right it matches on attribute. I will remove it, it is confusing and doesn't add anything.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, where do I put the library after I download it? I'm using Eclipse and I'm not sure how to properly import it!

Comment: I would suggest taking the time to learn and use maven. Aside from that, you have to [download it](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dom4j/files/dom4j/1.6.1/), drag it into your project from your download location, right click and select "add to build path". That should work.